# App closes without any error when I send BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast from ADB Shell

Tags: android, android-broadcast, bootcompleted

I have a boot complete broadcast receiver which was not being called when the phone restarted, so I removed everything from onReceive method, added a log statement and used ADB shell to send BOOT_COMPLETE broadcasts, now the app just closes down without any message when I send the broadcast and the status of the app goes to DEAD in the logcat package dropdown. 
I have the following permission defined in my Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Here is how I'm registering my receiver:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".BootCompleteBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I have tried without the android:exported="true" tag.
I am doing nothing in the onReceive method, I just have a log statement which is not being printed.

Here's the logcat, the apps seems to be force closed somehow, no error whatsoever:

```
04-24 19:34:28.639   768  1645 D ReceiverController: getBootReceiverEnabledSetting(com.vysh.theeye) at User(0) with identity: 1001
04-24 19:34:28.639   898   898 D AppChangedReceiver: kill back service:com.vysh.theeye
04-24 19:34:28.642   768  1633 V PackageController: forceStopPackage: com.vysh.theeye
04-24 19:34:28.642   768  1633 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.vysh.theeye appid=10119 user=0: from pid 768
04-24 19:34:28.643   768  1633 I ActivityManager: Killing 31461:com.vysh.theeye/u0a119 (adj 0): stop com.vysh.theeye
04-24 19:34:28.696   195   822 I BufferQueueProducer: [com.vysh.theeye/com.vysh.theeye.MainActivity](this:0xb4dd5000,id:270,api:1,p:-1,c:195) disconnect(P): api 1
04-24 19:34:28.697   195   822 I BufferQueueConsumer: [com.vysh.theeye/com.vysh.theeye.MainActivity](this:0xb4dd5000,id:270,api:1,p:-1,c:195) getReleasedBuffers: returning mask 0xffffffffffffffff
04-24 19:34:28.697   768  3699 I WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{a34299a u0 com.vysh.theeye/com.vysh.theeye.MainActivity}
04-24 19:34:28.697   768  3699 V WindowManager: Remove Window{a34299a u0 com.vysh.theeye/com.vysh.theeye.MainActivity} client=1866e45, surface=Surface(name=com.vysh.theeye/com.vysh.theeye.MainActivity) Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:1217 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:566 <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack>
04-24 19:34:28.699   195   195 I BufferQueueConsumer: [com.vysh.theeye/com.vysh.theeye.MainActivity](this:0xb4dd5000,id:270,api:1,p:-1,c:-1) disconnect(C)
04-24 19:34:28.700   768  1633 D ActivityManager: SVC-handleAppDiedLocked: app = ProcessRecord{f2d64fb 31461:com.vysh.theeye/u0a119}, app.pid = 31461
04-24 19:34:28.702   195   821 I BufferQueue: [com.vysh.theeye/com.vysh.theeye.MainActivity](this:0xb4dd5000,id:270,api:1,p:-1,c:-1) ~BufferQueueCore
04-24 19:34:28.704   768  1633 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.vysh.theeye/.WatcherService in 10229ms
04-24 19:34:28.705   768  1633 D ActivityManager: removeDyingProviderLocked: cpr=ContentProviderRecord{6c3aebd u0 com.vysh.theeye/com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider} always=false inLaunching=false
04-24 19:34:28.705   768  1633 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{e3b6f3d u0 com.vysh.theeye/.MainActivity t2248}: app died, no saved state
```

Comment: Interesting, can you open another terminal and check the full logcat with `adb logcat` or `adb logcat | grep "<your_package_name>"`

Comment: @KrzysztofKubicki Please check the edit.

Comment: include your main activity java file

Comment: @amir how would that help? I am registering the receiver in Manifest.

Comment: All the apps get killed?

Comment: If you need free help, dont be lazy

Comment: @Onik No, just my app.

Comment: Are you using a custom `Application` class? Please post your entire manifest. Also post the code of your `BroadcastReceiver`